# Convertng a Pandas series of stringg of '%d:%H:%M:%S' format into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, series

I have a Pandas series which consists of strings of '169:21:5:24', '54:9:19:29', and so on which stand for 169 days 21 hours 5 minutes 24 seconds and 54 days 9 hours 19 minutes 29 seconds, respectively.

I want to convert them to datetime object (preferable) or just integers of seconds.

The first try was

```
pd.to_datetime(series1, format = '%d:%H:%M:%S')
```

which failed with an error message

```
time data '169:21:5:24' does not match format '%d:%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

The second try

```
pd.to_datetime(series1)
```

also failed with

```
expected hh:mm:ss format
```

The first try seems to work if all the 'days' are less than 30 or 31 days, but my data includes 150 days, 250 days etc and with no month value.

Finally,

```
temp_list1 = [[int(subitem) for subitem in item.split(":")] for item in series1]
temp_list2 = [item[0] * 24 * 3600 + item[1] * 3600 + item[2] * 60 + item[3] for item in temp_list1]
```

successfully converted the Series into a list of seconds, but this is lengthy.

I wonder if there is a Pandas.Series.dt or datetime methods that can deal with such type of data.

Answer (score 0):

[[PyData.Pandas]: pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) uses (and points to) [[Python.Docs]: datetime - strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> - `%d` - **Day of the month** as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> ...
>
> - `%j` - **Day of the year** as a zero-padded decimal number.

So, you're using the wrong directive (correct one is ***%j***):

> ```py
> >>> import pandas as pd
> >>>
> >>> pd.to_datetime("169:21:5:24", format="%j:%H:%M:%S")
> Timestamp('1900-06-18 21:05:24')
> ```

As seen, the reference year is *1900* (as specified in the 2<sup>nd</sup> *URL*). If you want to use the current year, a bit of extra processing is required:

> ```py
> >>> import datetime
> >>>
> >>> cur_year_str = "{:04d}:".format(datetime.datetime.today().year)
> >>> cur_year_str
> '2023:'
> >>>
> >>> pd.to_datetime(cur_year_str + "169:21:5:24", format="%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
> Timestamp('2023-06-18 21:05:24')
> >>>
> >>> # Quick leap year test
> >>> pd.to_datetime("2020:169:21:5:24", format="%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
> Timestamp('2020-06-17 21:05:24')
> ```

All in all:

> ```py
> >>> series = pd.Series(("169:21:5:24", "54:9:19:29"))
> >>> pd.to_datetime(year_str + series, format="%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
> 0   2023-06-18 21:05:24
> 1   2023-02-23 09:19:29
> dtype: datetime64[ns]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert them to datetime object (preferable) **or just integers of seconds**.

It seems to me like you are rather looking for a `timedelta` because it's unclear what the year should be?

You could do that for example by (`ser` your series):

```py
ser = pd.Series(["169:21:5:24", "54:9:19:29"])
timedeltas = ser.str.split(":", n=1, expand=True).assign(td=lambda df:
    pd.to_timedelta(df[0].astype("int"), unit="D") + pd.to_timedelta(df[1])
)["td"]
seconds = timedeltas.dt.total_seconds().astype("int")
datetimes = pd.Timestamp("2022") + timedeltas  # year has to be provided
```

Result:

`timedeltas`:

```
0   169 days 21:05:24
1    54 days 09:19:29
Name: td, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

`seconds`:

```
0    14677524
1     4699169
Name: td, dtype: int64
```

`datetimes`:

```
0   2022-06-19 21:05:24
1   2022-02-24 09:19:29
Name: td, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```